# I am trying call an action in Dynamics CRM from KingswaySoft SSIS add-in and capture the response data and save to a database table

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

We have a Dynamics CRM action that we want to call from a KingswaySoft SSIS task and save the response data to a table. The response is a single record. I can't seem to get the KingswaySoft SSIS source to be an action. I wonder if it needs to be some form of API call rather than an OOTB source or destination.

Comment: If you are using a relatively recent version of Dynamics CRM (say 9.0 or above), you could possibly achieve so using our Premium OData Source component. Please reach out to our team so that we can share with you with further details. Generally, actions are not designed to be used as a source.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I believe we do have the Premium OData Source connector so am interested in looking at a Proof of Concept. Will reach to see what needs to be done to do this. I will also try to remember to post an update here on whether we succeed.